# SectionList - Animate on Section Press

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

We were asked to implement a screen for our app where there would be some data in the form of a list and sections for each data category. When a Section header is pressed, the section data should be expanded or collapsed.

At first, i tried with Listview, and i was changing the datasource each time a header was pressed, but tbh it did not feel like the correct way of doing it.

Creating a custom view, an animating the view's height works ok, but because of the volume of the data, which is big, the initial rendering is a bit slow e.g. there is a noticeable delay when navigating to the screen.

After upgrading to RN 44.3 i was wondering if i could use Sectionlist in a better way than listview.

Generally what's the best way of approaching a requirement like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can animate the items in flatlist/SectionList.  A smaple code will look like below (Animates on removing items). You can use same logic for section list as well.

```
onRemove = () => {
  const { onRemove } = this.props;
  if (onRemove) {
    Animated.timing(this._animated, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: ANIMATION_DURATION,
    }).start(() => onRemove());
  }
};
```

Refer this [link](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-animate-the-items-of-a-react-native-flatlist-32c8cbf7ea3d) for more details.